# Conditional formatting with date in formula

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I want a cell to be colored if the present day is equal to a date I wrote into a formula.

So I created conditional formatting with this special formula, for the F8 cell for instance:

```
TODAY()=DATE(2020,4,3)
```

Color green in the background

It doesn't work. And I really don't know why...

Any idea ?

Comment: you miss there leading equal sign...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in conditional formatting select **Custom formula** and enter this into the field:

```
=TODAY()=DATE(2020, 4, 3)
```

or if you have non-US locale:

```
=TODAY()=DATE(2020; 4; 3)
```

Comment: Thank you player0 ! I didn't know there was all these differences between US and non-US. Helpful.